# view the return value of method invocation

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, debugging

How could I view the value of `[fetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles]` in the debugger without change the code?

```
 return [fetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles];
```

Currently, I use to trick of add an tempory variable `s` and then use "print the descriptions of 's'" command. But this method requires me change the code so it is not convenient.

```
NSArray *s= [fetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles];
return s;
```

Similar, it would be very helpful to be able to see the value of `[a method1]` in following statement:

```
[b [a method1]]
```

Comment: Well, let's just say one of the WWDC 2012 videos holds an answer for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do use breakpoints ... Add breakpoint to your `return` line, right click on breakpoint, edit breakpoint and now you have two options ...

Add Action Debugger Command ...

```
expr (void)NSLog( @"%@", [fetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles] );
```

... or Log Message Action in a similar way and turn on Automatically continue after evaluating.

What it does?

Every time you hit your line with breakpoint, your application is paused, breakpoint actions are processed and as you did turn on Automatically continue after evaluating, your program continues when these breakpoint actions are processed. This is the way how to log, inspect, ..., without modifying your code.

Comment: It would be interesting a solution which doesn't actually call the method a second time. Maybe it's a part of a bad choice and that function also does some _(off-topic)_ stuff before returning.

Answer (score 4):

I found the trick:

After the breakpoint is hit, Simply type following command in the LLDB would do the job:

```
po [self.fetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles]
```

Where `po` is an abbreviation for `expression -o  --` used to print the object description of the value resulting from the expression.

Answer (score 1):

The return value is visible in Xcode debugger, immediately after returning from a function call (i.e. immediately after hitting the the "step out" button). See below screenshot for example:

[image]

Comment: Specifically, this info is in the 'Variables View' section of the Debug Area. If you closed that view a while ago, you can re-expand that pane by clicking on the button in the lower right section of the Debug Area, next to the trash icon.